# Centering a div with a dynamic width but using % for children width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with 100% height (parent 100% width 15% height), it contains children with 10% width and 100% height, but at certain actions an image is stored in it with 100% height and width set at auto.

While not setting any display options it's children width is taken from it's parent, unfortunately I can't use margin auto like that, if I set the display at table it centers it perfectly but the children's width is calculated by it's width, but I don't want to have any fixed width, neither I want to use % because when an image is placed in that child I get overflow. Changing the width will cause the children to change (I want them to stay the same at all time).

I am trying to avoid using jQuery on resize. Is there any possible way on positioning my div at the center (horizontally) ?

Everything I found required at least one known width (child, parent or its), but I don't have any. Is it possible for me to escape using JS or jQuery ?

EDIT:

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="center">
     <div class="child"> </div>
     <div class="child"> </div>
     .
     .
     .
     <div class="child"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
  position: relative
}
#parent{
  height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
}
.child{
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
}
#center{
  height: 100%;
}
```

NOTE: when an image is added in the child it's css is changed (it loses it's width property) :

```
height: 100%;
```

Image css:

```
height: 100%;
width: auto;
```

Comment: Show us some code... The html structure with it's css.

Comment: have you tried using `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` not sure if this is what you're looking for without the code present.

Comment: I've tried it doesn't work...